# Permisos de usuario entre bases de datos oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-12c

Agradezco de su colaboracion con la siguiente situacion. Tengo dos bases de datos diferentes (ej: `orcl1` y `orcl2`), la base de datos `orcl1` tiene varios usuarios-esquemas (`esquema1`, `esquema2`), la base de datos `orcl2` tiene un usuario-esquema `usrdb`. Debo dar permisos para que el usuario `usrdb` de la base de datos `orcl2` pueda hacer `crud` sobre las tablas del los esquemas `esquema1` y `esquema2` de la base de datos `orcl1`. La duda que tengo es ¿Como puedo otorgar esos permisos entre los usuario de bases de datos?

Comment: Cual sería la pregunta?

Comment: Necesitas algunos db-links y hacerles grant. que intentaste?

Comment: No, no sabia con que hacer esto, pero voy a revizar los db-links, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta corta es: **no puedes otorgar privilegios a un usuario de otra base de datos** en oracle.

Haciendo más larga esta respuesta:

Esto no significa que alguien conectado a una base de datos, no pueda modificar información que reside en otra base de datos, simplemente que debe utilizar un mecanismo de autenticación controlado mediante lo que se conoce como *db links*. En esencia, el db-link define los parámetros de conexión a la base de datos y la manera de autenticarse en ella, que puede ser mediante un usuario y contraseña que están *quemados* en el *db link*; es decir: todos los usuarios de la base de datos A, al aparecerán como el mismo usuario al realizar operaciones en la base de datos B, o puede ser el `CURRENT USER`.

La más sencilla es la primera, por ejemplo, en el host donde está tu base de datos `Orcl2`, configuras un alias TNS con los parámetros de `Orcl1` y ejecutas esta instrucción:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK rOrcl1 
   CONNECT TO Orcl2User IDENTIFIED BY Orcl2Password
   USING 'Orcl1';
```

En la base de datos Orcl1 debe existir el usuario *Orcl2User* y su contraseña *Orcl2Password*.

A partir de allí, todos los usuarios de Orcl2 podrán acceder a objetos de Orcl1 con los permisos de Orcl2User, por ejemplo, realizar:

```
select * from juan.Inventario@rOrcl1;
```

Si eso no te resulta suficiente, entonces, hablemos de *database links* para el `CURRENT USER`:

En este caso, los usuarios deben ser usuarios globales que deben existir en ambas bases de datos (LDAP).

La creación del database link es de esta manera:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK rOrcl1 
   CONNECT TO CURRENT_USER
   USING 'Orcl1';
```

El uso es igual, pero esta vez, cada usuario tendrá sus propios privilegios (que se otorgan localmente en cada base de datos, puesto que los usuarios existen en ambas).

Para más información, visita la documentación de la clausula [`GLOBALLY`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8003.htm#sthref8228) de `create user`, que se complementa con la del ejemplo [Defining a CURRENT_USER Database Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm#i2143859) de la documentación de `CREATE DATABASE LINK`